# wordpress goto external link

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have posttype.php which allows me to enter an externallink for each post i pull this links to display in the content via code

```
<div><a href=<?php get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'link', '', ', ', '' ); ?>> LINK </a></div>
```

now for e.g the link i enter is www.google.com then

when i click "`**LINK**`" it routes me to `mydomain.com`...how do i get it to go to www.google.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried prefixing your links with `http://`?

These usually specify absolute, external links. Everything else is treated as if it was on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try putting in double quotations before/after the PHP code?

If one thinks about it, a normal href will have these double quotes: i.e. `<a href="http://www.google.com">LINK</a>`

Comment: www.google.com is not put directly into the code...it grabs the link from the link taxonomy using the above code i mentioned

Comment: My point is that you should try putting **double quotes** in?
 `<div><a href="<?php get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'link', '', ', ', '' ); ?>"> LINK </a></div>`

Comment: nope not working it doesn't even grab the link as www.mydomain.com/www.google.com now...instead it just shows www.mydomain.com now

Comment: Actually, apologies, just had a thought... you're using `get_the_term_list` so by default this links to a page showing said terms without you actually having to actually link it.

As per http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list
`echo '<ul class="styles">';
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'styles', '<li>', ',</li><li>', '</li>' );
echo '</ul>';`

results in

`<ul class="styles">
    <li><a href="person1">Style 1,</a></li> 
    <li><a href="person2">Style 2,</a></li>
</ul>`